# I'm using Unity C# and Whenever I press down my finger to control the ball, the ball slows down how do I prevent that?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

my ball slows down when I press the screen, which is making the game go very slowly, When I let go the ball starts speeding up again because of gravity.

```
{
    private Vector3 touchPosition;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector3 direction;
    private float moveSpeed = 10;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            touchPosition.z = 0;
            direction = (touchPosition - transform.position);
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x, 0) * moveSpeed; 

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: @Jay I want the Ball to move left and right but it when I touch the screen to move the ball, the ball SLOWS down.

Comment: is the ball already moving? do you want it to only move left and right, and only when being touched? Is the ball affected by gravity?

Comment: @Jay the ball never stops moving due to Gravity, and since you have to touch the screen to move the ball, for some reason the ball slows down.

Comment: Can't test this right now, but try `direction.normalized.x`, your object slows down as direction.x is the distance between the finger and the ball. The normalization function sets these values to 1(used to get direction).

Comment: @ChilliPenguin changing it to ```rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.normalized.x, 0) * moveSpeed;``` didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Each time you press the button, you're telling the RigidBody you want the `y` velocity to be 0, essentially stopping to ball from falling.

Try this instead:

```
    private void Update ( )
    {
        if ( Input.touchCount > 0 )
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch ( 0 );
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint ( touch.position );
            touchPosition.z = 0;
            direction = ( touchPosition - transform.position );
            var v = rb.velocity;
            v.x = direction.x * moveSpeed;
            rb.velocity = v;

            if ( touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended )
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
```

Or, you could even just get the `x` component in the first place with:

```
var x = touchPosition.x - transform.position.x;
rb.velocity = new Vector2 ( x, rb.velocity.y );
```

Either way should do the trick. The second is *slightly* more performant.

Comment: @Izaan4200 that's one of two things 1) gravity (the most likely), or 2) you've made another error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to maintaining the current velocity of the object(horizontaly), then

`rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.normalized.x* rb.velocity.x, 0);`

You are currently resetting the velocity of the object to the movement speed to its basic speed (and the distance between your finger, which I dont believe you want). In addition, it is unclear if you have vertical movement with the 0 in y, which will stop the object's vertical movement. If you do you need the vertical movement to be maintain, you need to replace `0` with `rb.velocity.y`.

`rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.normalized.x* rb.velocity.x * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y );`

or

`rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.normalized.x * moveSpeed,1)* rb.velocity;`